# Can you use python to load a quick ruby script?

Tags: python, ruby, web, webautomation

I was curious if you could use python to load a quick ruby script? then continue with python.

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do that depending on your needs. Please be more specific.

Comment: I'm runnin selenium via py, then for some reason I can only get watir (ruby) to click something python cannot. therefore i wanted to load a ruby script to click something, then continue with py. @spectras

Comment: See [How to run Ruby code from Python](http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge), in particular, [unholy](https://github.com/whymirror/unholy).

Comment: What is `watir` doing that Python cannot do using selenium?

Comment: it clicks on a certain element id: that it can't seem to click in python selenium @PeterWood

Comment: i'll look into unholy as well @PeterWood

Comment: How are you selecting the element differently in watir than selenium?

Comment: i use the exact same value/text..um the variable name, but it just selects it in ruby, but won't in py. its weird. @PeterWood

Comment: im not sure how to use/install unholy @PeterWood ??

Comment: @marriedjane875 I'd go with the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [`call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) from `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['ruby', 'quick_script.rb', 'some_parameter'])
```

`Ruby` should be available from the `path` variable.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try it and see how it goes..